# Android: adding dialogOverlay on SurfaceView

Tags: android, xml, scala, overlay

I have an Android application that contains a setting. Inside of my setting I have a `CheckBoxPreference`. I want to show a picture overlay in one of my activities when the checkbox is activated.

My problem is that I don't know how I should call or show this `dialogOverlay` on `SurfaceView`.

Would you please give me some hints!
Thanks in advance!